# Does weak Hausdorffication preserve inclusions?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

There is a "weak Hausdorffication"-functor $wh$ from the category of compactly generated spaces (CG) to the category of compactly generated weak Hausdorff spaces (CGWH) given by quotienting out the smallest closed equivalence relation. It is left adjoint to the inclusion of CGWH into CG. (See Proposition 2.22 of [this note by Neil Strickland](http://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/courses/homotopy/cgwh.pdf))

Now given a map of CG spaces $A\rightarrow B$ that is an inclusion in the sense that it is a homeomorphism onto its image (By "image", I mean the set-theoretical image equipped with the regular subspace topology, so in particular it is already compactly generated without taking the CG-refinement.) Applying $wh$ gives a map $$wh(A)\rightarrow wh(B)$$ of CGWH spaces.

1. Is this map injective?
2. Is this map again a inclusion? (In the sense above?)
3. What else can I say about this map?

Answer (score 3):

The weak Hausdorffification of an inclusion need not even be injective.  For instance, let $B$ be an infinite set with the cofinite topology and let $A$ be any finite subset of $B$.  Then $A$ is discrete, and hence already weak Hausdorff.  But $B$ is not, and in fact its weak Hausdorffification is just a point.  So if $A$ has more than one point, the induced map $wh(A)\to wh(B)$ is not injective.