# Does weak Hausdorffication preserve equalizers and finite products?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

There is a "weak Hausdorffication"-functor $wh$ from the category of compactly generated spaces (CG) to the category of compactly generated weak Hausdorff spaces (CGWH) given by quotienting out the smallest closed equivalence relation. It is left adjoint to the inclusion of CGWH into CG. (See Proposition 2.22 of [this note](http://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/courses/homotopy/cgwh.pdf) by Neil Strickland)

1. Does $wh$ preserve equalizers?
2. Does $wh$ preserve pullbacks?
3. Does $wh$ preserve products?
4. Does $wh$ even preserve all finite limits?

Comment: An answer to your first question is provided by the answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599272/ Let $X$ be an infinite set with the cofinite topology. Then $X$ is sequential and thus a CG-space. Let $i:A\to X$ be the inclusion of some finite subspace with more than one point into $X$. This is the equalizer of $q,c: X\to X/i(A)$, where $q$ is the quotient map and $c$ is the constant map to $i(A)$. The weak Hausdorffication of $i: A \to X$ is the constant map $A \to \{*\}$, so it is not injective. But any equalizer in $CGWH$ injective. That means $wH$ does not preserve equalizers.