# Does Hausdorffication preserve finite limits?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, quotient-spaces

Does the left adjoint to the inclusion of T$_2$ spaces into the category of topological spaces preserve equalizers and finite products?

(Apologies if this question has already been posted, but I did't find it)

Answer (score 2):

It does not preserve equalizers. The example in Stefan Hamcke's comment to [Does weak Hausdorffication preserve equalizers and finite products?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1603259) applies also in the Hausdorff case.

Concerning products we can say the following.

For $x,x' \in X$ define $x \sim x'$ if any two open neighborhoods $U$ of $x$ and $U'$ of $x'$ intersect. Then the Hausdorffication of $X$ is given by $X/E$, where $E$ is the equivalence relation generated by $\sim$. Now let $X_\alpha$, $\alpha \in A$, be a family of spaces and $P = \prod_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$.

1) If $x_\alpha,x'_\alpha \in X_\alpha$ such that $x_\alpha \sim x'_\alpha$, then  $(x_\alpha) \sim (x'_\alpha)$ in $P$. Let $V, V'$ be open neigborhoods of $(x_\alpha), (x'_\alpha)$ in $P$. There exist $W \subset V, W' \subset V'$ having the form $W = \prod_{\alpha \in A} W_\alpha$, $W' = \prod_{\alpha \in A} W'_\alpha$ with open neighborhoods $W_\alpha$ of $x_\alpha$ and $W'_\alpha$ of $x'_\alpha$ in $X_\alpha$, such that almost all of them  are $=  X_\alpha$. But now $W_\alpha \cap W'_\alpha \ne \emptyset$ for all $\alpha$, therefore $V \cap V' \ne \emptyset$.

2) Let $(x_\alpha) \sim (x'_\alpha)$ in $P$. Consider any fixed $\alpha$ and any two open neighborhoods $W_\alpha$ of $x_\alpha$ and $W'_\alpha$ of $x'_\alpha$ in $X_\alpha$. Then $W = p_\alpha^{-1}(W_\alpha), W' = p_\alpha^{-1}(W'_\alpha)$ are open neigborhoods of$(x_\alpha), (x'_\alpha)$ in $P$. They must intersect, and this implies that $W_\alpha, W'_\alpha$ intersect. Therefore $x_\alpha \sim x'_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$.

This shows that there is a canonical continuous bijection $(\prod_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha)/\sim \phantom{.} \to \prod_{\alpha \in A} (X_\alpha/\sim)$. Whether this map is a homeomorphism is not known to me.

Comment: I'm really sorry to reopen this question after almost six months. When I read Paul' answers I was convinced, but now I have recognize a problem: Paul's proofs says that $(x_\alpha)\sim(x'_\alpha)$ if and only if $x_\alpha\sim x'_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$, but this does not show that 
$$\Pi_{\alpha\in A}X_\alpha/E\simeq (\Pi_{\alpha\in A}X_\alpha)/E$$
Even in the finite case, is there a map $X/E\times Y/E\to (X\times Y)/E$ ? Probably I'm just missing a trivial detail.

Comment: @Tolbiac You are right, I have only shown that there is a continuous bijection $(\prod_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha) / \sim \phantom{.} \to \prod_{\alpha \in A} (X_\alpha / \sim)$. I shall try to prove that this map is also open. If I do not succeed, I shall delete this part of my answer.

Comment: @Tolbiac I was not succesful and edited my answer. At least we know that Hausdorffication does not preserve all finite Limits.

Comment: It is explained here https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Hausdorffization that the quotient $X/E$ need not be Hausdorff. One has to repeat this construction (maybe even in a transfinite manner).