# A reflection map in the class of compact spaces is an embedding

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I have seen somewhere (emis.matem.unam.mx/journals/CMUC/pdf/cmuc9201/husek.pdf) that if $X$ has a reflection $r:X\longrightarrow Y$ in the class of compact spaces, then $r$ is an embedding and $Y$ may be found as a compactification of $X$.

Reflection: A space $Y$ from a class $C$ is a reflection of $X$ if $r:X\longrightarrow Y$ is a continuous map such that for every continuous mapping $f:X\longrightarrow Z$, where $Z$ is in $C$, there exists a unique continuous mapping $g:Y\longrightarrow Z$ such that $g \circ r=f$.

I have a problem with showing that $r$ is an embedding. Can it also happen that $r(X)$ is a dense subspace of $Y$?

Answer (score 0):

Whether $r$ is an embedding depends on the class $\mathfrak{C}$. Consider for example the class $\mathfrak{H}$ of Hausdorff spaces. Then each $X$ has an $\mathfrak{H}$-reflection $r : X \to h(X)$ (see for example [Does Hausdorffication preserve finite limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2907276) and https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/BachVanMunster.pdf). $r$ is a quotient map, in particular surjective. However, if $X$ is not Hausdorff, then  $r$ is not injective, hence not an embedding. In fact, $r$ is an embedding if and only if it is a homeomorphism if and only if $X$ is Hausdorff.

Each Tychonoff space $X$ (also called $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$-space) has reflection in the class $\mathfrak{CH}$ of comapct Hausdorff spaces. This is known as the Stone-Cech-compactification $\iota : X \to \beta X$ of $X$. See any book on general topology. In  that case $\iota$ is an embedding, and $\iota(X)$ is dense in $\beta X$.

Comment: Thank you @Paul. Will definitely look at that. Is it safe to declare that not every compact reflection of a space X is a compactification of X?

Comment: A compactification of a space $X$ is defined as an embedding of $X$ as a dense subset of some compact Hausdorff space $Y$. A necessary condition for $X$ to have compactification is that $X$ is a Tychonoff space. In that case usually there exist many distinct compactifications,but only the Stone-Cech-compactification has the reflection property. A compact Hausdorff reflection of a non-Tychonoff  space cannot be an embedding and is therefore not a compactfication.